# Express 50 to 100 with constituent digits only...my 100th pzl on 50th day

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle, no-computers

Using the following rules only, Express the numbers from 50 to 100 using only digits in the number. Concise with minimum number of characters is preferred.

No concatenation of numbers allowed.

Only, plus, minus, division, multiplication(use dot), exponentiation, factorial, brackets where needed are allowed.

No multiple factorials and exponents allowed.

Vinculum(compliments of 10) allowed if you prefer. 
For example, 3 underlined is 7...9 underlined is 1.

See examples..in the picture..in red...blue ..normal way

I have filled in some..not necessarily optimum.

[image]

Comment: So what's the question, exactly? Do you have to optimize every single one of these, or just accomplish them?

Comment: Concise form is preferred..otherwise one can write long expressions for any number

Comment: Only for 1 to 9..if you see what I have written for 77...you can see it’s useful..very useful in simplifying various math operations.

Comment: You don’t have to use it..if you are not comfortable with it..you can express normal way..see 63 and 91..I expressed in both ways

Comment: The concise form is "preferred", but what counts as a *solution*? This seems like an activity, not a puzzle.

Comment: Yes..77=7.7 +7.7underline+7

Comment: @deusovi I have given similar puzzles before..people started concatenations, writing long expressions..you are deducing the optimum path..of course by definition..everything is an activity

Comment: So, are you required to find the optimal path for every number? What counts as a solution? The question doesn't ask for the optimal path, meaning there's not really much puzzle here. It sounds like you're treating this as primarily an activity for people to *participate in*, rather than a puzzle for people to *solve*.

Comment: Concise with minimum number of characters is preferred....that is given in the puzzle..why are we splitting hairs?

Comment: There are at least 20 puzzles like this with far more extensive activities required..check similar puzzles from 1 to  100 writing in all kinds of convoluted ways..I prefer simple concise..that’s what I am asking for..if you are going to judge this puzzle..use the same yardstick for all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Vinculum:

> $\underline{a}=10-a$

we have:

> $\overline{ab}=10a+b=a(a+\underline{a})+b$, which solves all of them.

Comment: That is not what it is intended for..it is trivial solution..you are technically correct